# Find and replace first occurrence of a string in a series of strings in an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, intellij-idea, replace

I have an ArrayList that houses a series of notes in the form of "take out the trash", "do the dishes" etc. I have a notes class with a method that is supposed to find and replace the first occurrence of a string given by the user, such as "do", in each note (if there is one) and replace that string with a new one given by the user. For example: if I have multiple notes that start off as "do x" the "do" in each note should become "do not". This is my method so far:

```
public void findAndReplaceFirst(String old, String newWord) {
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
                String note = notes.get(i);
                if (note.contains(old)) {
                    int loc = note.indexOf(old);
                    int len = old.length();
                    String temp = note.substring(0, loc ) + note.substring(loc + len, note.length());
                    String newString = temp.substring(0, loc) + newWord + temp.substring(loc, temp.length());
                } else {
                    String newString = note;
                }
            }
        }
```

However, when I run the main method, the string of notes comes out unchanged and I don't understand why. Could anybody tell me where in the method I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String comes out unchanged because Java doesn't allow variable change passed to methods. In Java, all objects are passed to methods by value. You will have to return the `newString` from the `findAndReplaceFirst` method.

You could also use the `replaceFirst` method defined in String class:

```
public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement);
```

Say you want to replace all occurences of "do" with some user input, the following code uses `List`'s `set(int index, E element)` method to replace an element at the specific index.

Assuming `notes` is type or subtype of `List<String>`:

```
String userInput = /* get user input */

for (int i = 0, n = notes.length(); i < n; i++) {
    String str = notes.get(i).replaceFirst("do", userInput);
    notes.set(i, str);
}
```

Comment: That would also work but I just figured it out. I had to add notes.set(i, newString) and the string was replaced in the ArrayList. Thanks for explaining why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You created a modified String called `newString` but you actually have to put it back in the list using `set()`. Just before the end of the for loop, add `notes.set(i, newString);`.